# Linking two tables in an MVC 3 project using the Entity Framework?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4, model

(Running EntityFramework 4.1)
I have a ASP .NET MVC 3 project that has a database with two database tables.

The models that express the database tables:

```
public class MyDetails
{
    public int DetailsID {get;set;}
    public string Description {get;set;}
    public int 
    public CarID {get;set;}
    public virtual Cars Cars {get;set;}

    public PreviousCarID {get;set;}

}

public class Cars
{
    public int CarsID {get;set;}
    public string CarsName {get;set;}


}
```

Entity Framework will nicely relate the MyDetails.CarsID and the Cars.CarsID so that I can pull the CarsName.
The issue is that I'm not sure how to relate PreviousCarID to the Cars table.

What I've tried (results in an Entity Framework error):

```
public PreviousCarID{get;set;}
[ForeignKey("PreviousCarID")]
public virtual Cars Cars2 {get;set;}
```

Comment: `MyDetails` class is messed up. Can you update?

Answer (score 0):

I would rename Cars to Car, and change CarsID to CarID.  Then leave in your DbContext the DbSet as type Car, but named Cars.

Second, to address your specific problem (using my recommendation above)

```
public class MyDetails 
{ 
    public int DetailsID {get;set;} 
    public string Description {get;set;} 
    public int CarID {get;set;} 
    public int PreviousCarID {get;set;}

    public virtual Car Car {get;set;} 
    public virtual Car PreviousCar {get;set;} 
} 

public class Car 
{ 
    public int CarID {get;set;} 
    public string CarName {get;set;} 
}
```

You don't say whether you are using Code First, Model First, or Database First.  I'll assume Database First.  If that's the case, then you need to make sure that both CarID and PreviousCarID are foreign keys to the Car table.